# Enabling permanently review checkbox option for all WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, review

I would like to **enable** review checkbox permanently for all existing products and for newly added products too. I have looked in WooCommerce settings, but thatís not possible. I have search over internet, and I didnít find anything.

How can I bulk edit all existing products to get reviews **Enabled**?

When we add a new product it should be automatically checked too.

Is there a way to do it? 
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **This is possible**, but you will need 2 functions. One to update all existing products inn your shop, that you will use only one time, and the other for all newly published products.

**Step 1** - Use this just once on function.php and go to front-end and navigate to any page. Once done comment this code or remove it. **All your existing products have been updated.**

```
// Updating all products that have a 'comment_status' => 'closed' to 'open'

function updating_existing_products_once(){
    $args = array(
        // WC product post type
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        // all posts
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    $shop_products = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $shop_products as $item){
        $product = new WC_Product($item->ID);
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID'    => $item->ID,
            'comment_status' => 'open',
        ) );
    }
}
// After usage comment this line below
updating_existing_products_once();
```

**Step 2** - This function will update new created products that have a 'comment_status' => 'closed' to 'open' *(reviews on WooCommerce)*…

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'creating_a_new_product', 10, 3);
function creating_a_new_product($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if( $old_status != 'publish' && $new_status == 'publish' && !empty($post->ID)  && in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'product') ) ) {
        if ($post->comment_status != 'open' ){
            $product = new WC_Product($post->ID);
            wp_update_post( array(
                'ID'    => $post->ID,
                'comment_status' => 'open',
            ) );
        }
    }
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**This code is tested and works.**

Answer (score 3):

In addition to LoicTheAztec's excellent answer, I'd like to add a different option for "Step 1".

You could just run a simple query that doesn't require iterating over a loop:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} SET comment_status = 'open' WHERE post_type = 'product'");
```

Note the *intentional* omission of the `comment_status` and `post_status` in the `WHERE` clause.  It would not matter that unpublished products have an open comment status, nor would it matter that products that already have comment_status set to open are being re-set to open.

Just add the above code to the bottom of your theme's `functions.php` file, and then comment them out after it has been run once:

```
// Commented out so it won't run
// global $wpdb;
// $wpdb->query("UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} SET comment_status = 'open' WHERE post_type = 'product'");
```

Comment: Thanks for compliment… Could you do also Step2 in the same way, to get a **complete answer**, please :) … This could be useful to the community.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - your method is - in my opinion - the best / right way to do #2.  My method is only an alternate to step 1.  I would never copy part of someone's answer into my own to make it complete, therefore I stopped where I did to just offer an alternate to step 1.  I *considered* posting the code for a full plugin, with a button to "enable all comments", but felt like it was overkill....

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question but function below could help someone if LoicTheAztec's answer won't work (like for me). It will check reviews' checkbox by default by using jQuery on "Add product" page. I hope help someone, cheers! :-)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_advanced', 'enable_reviews_by_default' );
function enable_reviews_by_default() {
?>
    <script>
        (function($){
            $('input[name=comment_status]').prop('checked', true);
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way a dirty method of fixing things immediately (reversable). All credits to a guy Evgeniy

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_open/

While the original thread discusses how to disable comments everywhere, I reversed the effect :)

This disables the possibility for you to decide on a per-product basis, because overrides the checkbox site-wide!

Disclaimer: do at your own risk!

add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_true' );